# Disabled back button in ios while loading and enable it once loading is complete

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I want to disabled back button provided by react navigation on header, while a particular API is loading on my page.

I am able to do `pointerEvents='none'` of whole page during API call, but header back is enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Im going to assume you're using **React Navigation x5**. There are so many ways you could achieve that, Im going to provide one solution and let me know if it works.

In the screen where you're making the api call, create a new state variable `goBackDisabled` and set it to `true` initially:

```js
      const [goBackDisabled, setGoBackDisabled] = useState(true)
```

Now after your api call finishes you can set `goBackDisabled` to `false`. Something like this:

```js
    const apiCallHandler = async ()=> {
        try {
          const someResponse = await apiCall();
          setGoBackDisabled(false);
        } catch (err) {
          // handle api call errors... 
          // You may want to enable going back in case of an error...
        }
      }
```

All that's left is set up your back button. For that, you need to assign a custom back button yourself by overriding `headerLeft` property in the `options` of your `Stack.Screen`. To achieve that in the same current screen where you're making the api call, you have to use the `navigation.setOptions()` method that accepts an object which customizes the different properties of your screen depending on the current state of the screen.

Set your custom button `disabled` property to the `goBackDisabled` state variable. By doing that, your custom button enability will depend upon the `goBackDisabled` state which in turn depends upon your api call.

Here's an example button that achieves that:

```js
      React.useLayoutEffect(()=>{
        navigation.setOptions({
          headerLeft: () => <Button disabled = {goBackDisabled} onPress = {()=> navigation.goBack()} />,
        });
      }, [goBackDisabled, navigation]);
```